# Hiding definitions for private symbols in a shared library

Tags: c++, linux, linker, shared-libraries

I have a header file like this:

```
File A.hpp: 
#include "spdlog/spdlog.h"
class A
{
  public:
    ...templated functions using spdlog::logger and spdlog::sink_ptr
  private:
    std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> spdlog_logger;
    std::vector<spdlog::sink_ptr> sinks;
    ...and some more regular member functions defined in cpp file
}
```

The class A is singleton wrapper for spdlog. spdlog uses variable argument lists for its logging functions. To make use of that I have templated member functions defined inline in the header.

A.hpp together with spdlog headers and the corresponding source files are compiled as a shared library by cmake on linux.

The problem is that I do not want any of the spdlog symbols exposed to the components which link to that library.

I cannot see any way of workarounding this.
I know there are possiblities of hiding symbols in a library(map files, atribute "hidden" and so on.

But since the header itself must include the spdlog header the dependent components will all try to include the spdlog headers as well even if the symbols would be hidden.

This comes down to the problem that:
I have to include the spdlog headers in A.hpp because of the spdlog members.
Even if I wouldnt use template functions and move all logic in to cpp I would need to include spdlog in the header because private members have to be included in the class (otherwise compiler cannot determine correct class size)

The problem is not with spdlog and can occur with any other code as well. I just included that detail because I believe it might make the problem more clear.

I hope I described the problem well enough.
Any suggestion is strongly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is not specific to _shared_ libraries.

Comment: Well, this comment is not really helpful. Why dont you suggest better hashtags if the chosen ones do not match your expectation.  I have tried to describe the problem with my best knowledge. Including the hashtags. I am open to constructive critic.

Comment: You may use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl here

Comment: "Well, this comment is not really helpful" - sorry, I meant to say that your concerns may apply to static libs as well.

Comment: @Bktero you could make this an answer (but it should be self-contained, not just external link), I'd +1 it.